# Eclipse: Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected

Tags: eclipse, firebase, jsp

I was trying Firebase connectivity for my web application but the code continually displays error on `catch` keyword.

Here's my code, under login function of sign in screen:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail,userPassword).catch(Exception) {};
```

Comment: It seems like you are using the wrong syntax. Try 

```.catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
}); ``` 
as descrebed here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

Comment: That's JavaScript code, but invalid Java code (because `catch` is a keyword in Java and keywords can not be used as method names). Where do you use the code? In a `.jsp` file you can use JavaScript and Java code, depending on where you use it.